# How to create Nested items in recyclerview

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` and my items needs to be overlapped. I've struggled a lot on internet. Can anyone help me how to achieve that?

Reference: See the attached image

[image]

Comment: you should use negative margin with clipToChildren

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @ConfusedPup it is now nested,thanks, but now the problem is that the half of the item is cut by giving the negative margin.

Comment: @VishistVarugeese please chek the gist https://gist.github.com/Talha089/ad6680f8a11e2a81efed173b0a559899

Comment: now every parent of that view and their parents needs to be specified as clipChildren=false clipPadding=false @TalhaJavaidMalik

Comment: Glad I helped my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
As Described in the above comments by @ConfusedPup, By giving negative margin to the item of recyclerview and setting 
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false".
I've achiieved the solution of above problem.